# How does Grammerly partially style the input texts that are wrong?

Tags: html, css

I want to style the user input dynamically based on certain validation conditions.

After doing research online it appears that css styling applied within the input either has to be applied to the entire input search box.

I want to have an end result that looks like this where the error/invalid text has a special styling to highlight them dynamically. Please help! 
[image]

Comment: You are looking for some WHYSWYG editor with spelling checker. Basically you wrap word in `<span>` with special style and text is copy-paste from actual textarea

Comment: I see you didn't add `javascript` to your tags, but I think Grammarly is doing this with javascript. (I'm pretty sure dynamically updating is mostly done with javascript)

Comment: add `spellcheck="true"` to the input of your chioce